# discard dynamic characters in string with replace()

Tags: javascript, jquery

for example 21/10/2013.. I want to remove the /2013..

`replace('/2013', '')` work but the date might be other value like 2014, 2015 and so on

Comment: If it's always in this format, could you split, pop, then join?

Comment: "21/10/2013".replace(/\/\d{4}$/g,'');

Comment: @CoreyRothwell: comments are not for answering the question if you know it works - if it does answer the question (which it does), please post it as an answer.  Thansk!

Comment: Why not just `.substring(0, 5)`, assuming the day and month values are zero-padded.

Comment: Or `.slice(-5)`, assuming this is not meant to be used in the year 10k+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This removes everything from the last `/` onwards:

```
var str = "21/10/2013";
var new_str = str.substring(0,str.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
'21/10/2013'.replace(/\/\d+$/,''); // 21/10
```

which removes the last "/" and any digits following to the end of the string.